# How to remove a Gmail account I added

Tags: gmail

I recently added, to my "main" Gmail account, another account:

[image]

I want to detach those accounts from each other (not deleting) but can't find this option.

Where is it?

Answer (score -2):

Google Accounts are not OS Specific. the root has to be in the google account. android wont see it if you click on your account and on main page "Delete your account or services" simple.